# Deploying multiple Grails instances with shared cache and sessions?

Tags: grails, deployment, load-balancing, ehcache, cluster-computing

I am looking for a solution that allows me to deploy multiple load balanced Grails instances that have shared cache (EhCache Server ?) and sessions, is this possible ?

I can't find any documentation on this (connecting to a common EhCache server or using Distributed EhCache, and sharing sessions (using EhCache too ?))...

I'm looking for something that will work like multiple Rails instances with a common memcached and sessions/caches stored in the memcached...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was recently listening to a talk by [Dave Klein](http://dave-klein.blogspot.com/), author of the book "Grails: A Quick Start Guide", and Mike Allen, Product Managemer at Terracotta about [Clustering and Scaling Grails applications](http://bit.ly/aeDQ3I).

They introduced Terracotta as a great tool for exactly solving your issues and showed needed steps to share session within multiple instances of your Grails applicatons.

So if you want to go with Terracotta the [Grails Terracotta Plugin](http://www.grails.org/Terracotta+Plugin) might be very useful for you.

**EDIT**
On the EHCache website you will now find a short [introduction to using EHCache with Grails](http://ehcache.org/recipes/grails.html).

Comment: Thank you ! I can see this allows session centralization, but does it allows cache centralization ?

Comment: It allows performance optimization by distributed caching. See http://www.terracotta.org/start/distributed-cache-tutorial for a informative tutorial.