# Grails httpsession

Tags: database, http, session, grails

Is it possible to store Grails session in Database? After starting a load balancer my app randomly asks users to login (almost on every other webpage redirection). I know I can enable sticky sessions but I have seen it with rails that sessions can be saved in db so there would be no problems in multi server environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the database is the hardest part of an app to scale. It's pretty easy to horizontally scale by adding more web servers, but you usually vertically scale the database. So it doesn't make much sense to add more work to your database by storing sessions there in addition to your real application data.

See this blog post for a simple way to cluster Grails in multiple Tomcat servers and enable session replication: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/07/20/basic-tomcat-clustering-grails-applications

Comment: Really useful link, thanks. Slight nitpick though; the comment that using DB sessions "doesn't make much sense" comes from the mindset that apps have to achieve maximum scalability at any cost. Not all apps are destined to grow like that, and in those cases persisting sessions to the database may make an awful lot of sense.

Comment: Yep, in fact I wrote a plugin to do this: http://grails.org/plugin/database-session

Answer (score 0):

Terracotta might allow you do that (I haven't used it so I don't know it's mechanism for sharing between servers).  There is a Terracotta plugin for Grails, [which is suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732958/deploying-multiple-grails-instances-with-shared-cache-and-sessions).

Comment: Terracotta is a good way to go, but the plugin is very old and should be avoided.